# Laravel - Single query then splitting Vs Two queries

Tags: php, laravel, optimization

I am using laravel framework and I need to get 2 arrays, one with premium themes and one with free themes.. so I would do:

```
$premium_themes = \App\Theme::where('premium', '=', '1')->get();
$free_themes = \App\Theme::where('premium', '=', '0')->get();
```

This will work Ok, but will perform two queries on the database. Since I'm an optimization geek, I think it might be better to have a single query... which I would get all themes by using:

```
$themes = \App\Theme::all();
```

And then I'd to process this in php to split based on the theme premium property.

So I have 2 questions:

1) A single query is better than 2 queries in this case, or am I over-thinking this?

2) Is there a fast simple way to split the resulting collection into two collections based on the premium property? (I know Laravel has many shortcuts but I'm still new to the framework)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single query would be better as both of the queries will go over all the rows in the database. Except the 2 queries to split them will go over them for a second time.

You can simply filter them like so;

The simple one line solution `$themes = \App\Theme::all()->groupBy('premium');`.

Or into separate collections if you need to filter by another element etc just add more to the following;

```
$themes = \App\Theme::all();

$premium = new Collection;
$free = new Collection;

$themes->each(function ($item) use ($premium, $free){
    if($item->premium == '1'){
        $premium->push($item);
    } 
    else {
        $free->push($item);
    }
});
```

And your items will be filtered into the relevant `Collection`. Be sure you use the `Collection` class at the top.

Comment: I found an simple one line solution.. what do you think of this Matt?:

    $themes = \App\Theme::all()->groupBy('premium'));

Comment: @RaphaelCabrera Edited to include this.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think to keep it as separate queries would be if you need to paginate the data - not something you can do easily if its all mixed together.

A "short cut" would be to use the collection `filter()` method, I put short cut in quotes because it's not short per-se, more syntatic sugar - but Larvel is nothing if not full of sugar so why not?

Code would look something like this:

```
$allThemes = \App\Theme::all();

$premiumThemes = $allThemes->filter(function($theme)
{
    return $theme->premium;
});

$freeThemes = $allThemes->filter(function($theme)
{
    return !$theme->premium;
});
```

Edit: I'd recommend using Matt Burrow's answer, but I'll leave mine here as the solution is different.